# Running gulp task from one gulpfile.js from another gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Perhaps it's something wrong with my approach but I have a following situation:

1. I have a `component-a` that has a gulpfile. One of its tasks (eg. build) builds the component and creates a combined js file in dist folder
2. I have a `component-b` that has a gulpfile. One of its tasks (eg. build) builds the component and creates a combined js file in dist folder
3. I have a project that uses both components. This project has a gulpfile as well and in it I would like to write a task that:

   - executes build task from /components/component-a/gulpfile.js
   - executes build task from /components/component-b/gulpfile.js
   - concats /components/component-a/dist/build.js and /components/component-b/dist/build.js (I know how to do this)

What I don't know is how to execute the build task from /components/component-?/gulpfile.js. Is it even possible or I should deal with this situation otherwise?

Comment: Could you please accept Walter Roman's answer as this is correct and working?

Answer (score 23):

## require('child_process').spawn;

Running a Gulpfile from a different directory is quite simple with [Node's `child_process#spawn` module](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Try adapting the following to your needs:

```js
// Use `spawn` to execute shell commands with Node
const { spawn } = require('child_process')
const { join } = require('path')

/*
  Set the working directory of your current process as
  the directory where the target Gulpfile exists.
*/
process.chdir(join('tasks', 'foo'))

// Gulp tasks that will be run.
const tasks = ['js:uglify', 'js:lint']

// Run the `gulp` executable
const child = spawn('gulp', tasks)

// Print output from Gulpfile
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    if (data) console.log(data.toString())
})
```

## gulp-chug

Although using `gulp-chug` is one way to go about this, [it has been blacklisted by `gulp`'s maintainers](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/issues/93#issuecomment-42715640) for being...

> "execing, too complex and is just using gulp as a globber"

The [official blacklist](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/master/src/blackList.json#L99) states...

> "no reason for this to exist, use the require-all module or node's require"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help someone too, so I'll give this a shot. I don't know specifically what the OP intends to do but the question is similar to my problem which my solution is to access the other gulp file in another way like using a project's pre-build event, for example:

```
cd $(SolutionDir)\ProjectThatHasTargetGulpFile
gulp theTaskNeedToRun
```

Considering that Gulp and NodeJs is properly installed in the machine (can run in cmd).