# javascript gulp: returning stream from chug submodule

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm a noob with gulp, so what I'm trying to do might not be possible, but I would appreciate some help.

Our project consists of several isolated modules, that I would like to be able to build independently, or to build altogether as one project. The file structure looks like this:

```
project_root/
    gulpfile.js
    src/
        modules/
            module_A/
                gulpfile.js
                ...
            module_B/
                gulpfile.js
                ...
            module_C/
                gulpfile.js
```

I would like to place build artifacts in a `build/` directory at the top level, while preserving the directory structure of the `src/` dir, like so:

```
project_root/
    build/
        modules/
            module_A/
                ...
            module_B/
                ...
            module_C/
                ...
```

To achieve this, I'm trying to use the gulpfile at the top level to discover any file that matches a glob like `src/modules/*/gulpfile.js`, and then to call each of these using the plugin `gulp-chug`. I would like to then return a stream from the submodule's `gulpfile.js` and allow the base build file handle piping to `dest` in order to simply manage preserving the folder structure.

The code I have to do this looks like so:

```
// project_root/gulpfile.js
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.join(modulesDir, '*', 'gulpfile.js')) // discover subprojects
        .pipe( chug() )                     // call gulpfiles in those subprojects
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDir));                            // write the output to the build dir
});
```

And

```
// src/modules/module_x/gulpfile.js
gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src(path.join(config.sourceDir, '**', '*.js'));  // return a stream of source files
});
```

However, what I'm seeing happen is that the `gulpfile.js` files from my submodules get copied into the `build/` dir, but not any of the other source files.

I think that this means that the line `.pipe( chug() )` is not returning the stream of objects I expected to get out of the submodule, but I don't understand why.

Have I completely misunderstood how this should work? Is there some other pattern I should be using?

Comment: From reading [this thread](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/issues/93), it seems that the gulp.js project doesn't approve of chug, so I'll probably steer clear of that. I'm left with the same problem of how to host isolated subprojects within a master gulp project. The solution suggested in that thread (`require-all`, `require-dir`) looks like it would have some unfortunate scaling problems, specifically to do with namespacing.

Comment: Okay, [another thread](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/919) on the gulpjs project reveals more. User kosz put together [a sample project](https://github.com/kosz/research-is-gulp-chug-needed) that shows how to provide some namespace separation of submodules using a construct like `var gulp1 = require('./proj1/gulpfile.js');` This provides a lot of the behaviour I would like, using built-in nodejs constructs, which suits my purposes. Outputting build artifacts to a folder structure at the top level next...

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664725/running-gulp-task-from-one-gulpfile-js-from-another-gulpfile-js